# Sequelize orphan removal when deleting parent

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables in mysql:

```
create table comments
(
    id                 int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    postId             varchar(100)                not null,
    text               text                        not null,
    constraint commentForPost foreign key (postId) references posts (id)
);

create table post
(
    id               varchar(100)                        not null primary key,
    name             varchar(100)                        not null,
);
```

and the two following models in sequelize:
post.js file:

```
class Post extends Model {}

Post.init({
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: 'Post', // We need to choose the model name
    tableName: 'posts',
    timestamps: false
});


Post.hasMany(Comment, { foreignKey: 'postId', onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
Comment.belongsTo(Post, { foreignKey: 'postId' });
```

comment.js file:

```
class Comment extends Model {}
Comment.init({
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    postId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    text: {
        type: DataTypes.text,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: 'Comment', // We need to choose the model name
    tableName: 'comments',
    timestamps: false
});
```

Now I would like to delete the comments of a post when I delete the post. The code I'm using is the following:

```
  const post = await Post.destroy({
    where: {id}
  });
```

this generates the following query:

```
DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '1'
```

and the error I'm getting is the following:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError:
> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`db`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `commentForPost` FOREIGN KEY (`postId`)
> REFERENCES `posts` (`id`))

My sequelize version is: **6.3.5**

How can I achieve deleting the post and also deleting the "orphan" comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` and this option will work but for `sequelize.sync` call only (to create a foreign key with this option). Usual `destroy` calls don't take into account this option. So you should manually change an exising foreign key to set `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample on how I could achieve this?

Comment: First drop a foreign key `ALTER TABLE comments DROP FOREIGN KEY commentForPost` then create it again with CASCADE option: `ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT commentForPost FOREIGN KEY (postId) references posts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. Maybe these two commands are a little inaccurate, please check against the MySQL documentation